# Permutation on bracelet

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

In how many ways can seven different colored beads be made into a bracelet?

By seven different colour we get $7!$. Since it is a bracelet it can go either clockwise or anti clockwise. Hence it would be $2(7!)$.

Am I correct sir, I still have doubts?

Comment: Think if clockwise and anticlockwise are so different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we have $n$ beads of different colours, then we have $(n-1)!$ ways of making a necklace, because we may consider this situation as a circular permutation.

Here, $n=7$. So, ?

Comment: You just typed a formula and gave it to him. Tell him how he was wrong then tell him how should it be solved.